# How can I calculate the value of $a^4+ \frac {1}{a^4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

given that **$a$** is real positive number 
such that $a^3+ \frac {1}{a^3}=18$ How can I calculate the value of $a^4+ \frac {1}{a^4}$ ?

Comment: What is the context of this problem?  Have you tried to solve it?  If so, what difficulty did you actually encounter?  Supplying these details will assist a willing Reader to provide an Answer suitable to your level of effort and understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \stackrel{\rm def}{=}a + \frac{1}{a}$. First, show that $x^3 = 3x + 18$; which implies $x = 3$. From there, we get (by computing $x^2$ then $x^4$)
$$\frac{1}{a^2} + a^2 = 7$$
and 
$$\frac{1}{a^4} + a^4 = 47.$$

Comment: How did you see x=3 without graphing the equation? This is where I got stuck.

Comment: Nice solution. [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write math on this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** find the value of $a>0$. To do so, it suffices to find the value of $a^3$: do you know how to solve $A+\frac{1}{A}=\alpha$ for $A>0$?

Comment: I really dont know how but if u told me I will try it in this exercice :D

Comment: Multiply both sides by $A$ and rearrange the terms: you only need to solve $A^2-\alpha A + 1=0$ for $A$.

Comment: This solution will require a calculator (to solve using quadratic formula). Is there no way to solve this without calculator? I suspect there must be since the solution is coming as an integer - 47 .

Comment: You can write the expression and try to simplify it without a calculator.

Comment: I tried. I am not able to.

Comment: @Joe: There may very well be a simpler solution (not involving the computation of $a$) — I do believe there is. For reference, the answer is 47.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $t=a^3$, then:

$a^3+\frac{1}{a^3}=18\implies$

$t+\frac{1}{t}=18\implies$

$t^2-18t+1=0\implies$

$t=\frac{18\pm\sqrt{324-4}}{2}\implies$

$a^3=\frac{18\pm\sqrt{324-4}}{2}\implies$

$a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{18\pm\sqrt{324-4}}{2}}\implies$

$a^4+\frac{1}{a^4}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{18\pm\sqrt{324-4}}{2}}^4+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{18\pm\sqrt{324-4}}{2}}^4}=47$

Answer (score 2):

$a^4+\dfrac1{a^4}=\big(a^2\big)^2+\bigg(\dfrac1{a^2}\bigg)^2=\bigg(a^2+\dfrac1{a^2}\bigg)^2-2.\quad$ Similarly, $a^2+\dfrac1{a^2}=\bigg(a+\dfrac1a\bigg)^2-2$.

At the same time, $a^3+\dfrac1{a^3}=\bigg(a+\dfrac1a\bigg)\bigg(a^2+\dfrac1{a^2}-1\bigg).~$ Letting $S_n=a^n+\dfrac1{a^n}~,~$ we have

$~S_2=S_1^2-2,\quad~S_3=S_1~\Big(S_2-1\Big)=S_1~\Big(S_1^2-3\Big)=18,\quad~S_4=S_2^2-2.~$ It is trivial to

notice that $S_1=3$ is a solution for $S_3=18,~$ implying $S_2=7~$ and $~S_4=47$.